# How to register a netbeans custom DataLoader

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, annotations, netbeans-plugins

Hello I have created a custom `MultiFileLoader` and am wondering how I would register it to the `DataLoaderPool` when creating a Netbeans plugin.

```
https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/netbeans-src/java/src/org/netbeans/modules/java/JavaDataLoader.java.shtml
http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/MultiFileLoader-being-called-multiple-times-for-same-file-td3026758.html
```

I don't know if there is a way to do this with an @Annotation or if I have to add it to the Netbeans `Layers.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to references found on the web, there is no annotation.
Correct way to do it is either:

1. Use the MANIFEST/services to register it (see [DataLoader FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqDataLoader) )
2. Use the layer.xml (see [INTViewer plugin site](https://sites.google.com/a/geotoolkit.net/intviewer/other-useful-intviewer-apis/dataloaders) )

The documentation doesn't give a lot of details.
Hereunder are more detailed explanation:

### Manifest approach

Easy to implements but inefficient. The DataLoader methods are called for any FileObject encountered by Netbeans. This mean any file on disk but also any files in the virtual filesystems like the layer filesystem.

**How to**:

1. Create a file in the directory META-INF/services in your src directory of your project called org.openide.loaders.DataLoader
2. Write in it the qualified class name of your DataLoader.

### Layer.xml approach

The layer approach is a lot more complicated but also a lot more powerful. By relying on the mime type, you can tie more functionalities to you specific DataObject like custom actions, editors...

The required elements in the layer xml are:

- *Registration of a specific MimeResolver* : recognize a file and assign a Mime Type to it.
- *Entry in the Loaders filesystem* : Instruct Netbeans to use your custom DataLoader when it encounter a file with the specific Mime Type.

### Example

- Suppose that we define an xml file format with the mime type text/brain+xml with the namespace *http://foo.bar.brain*
- The custom Data loader is called foo.bar.brain.BrainDataLoader
- The custom Data object is called foo.bar.brain.BrainDataObject
- Your xml file will start with a tag like

  ```
  <brain xmlns="http://foo.bar.brain" name="sample brain 1"/>
  ```

foo.bar.brain.BrainDataObject file will start with the following annotations:

```
    @Messages({
        "LBL_Brain_LOADER=Files of Brain"
    })
    @MIMEResolver.NamespaceRegistration(
        displayName = "#LBL_Brain_LOADER",
        mimeType = "text/brain+xml",
        elementNS = {"http://foo.bar.brain"}
    )
```

Your layer.xml file will look like (only relevant part shown):

```
<filesystem>        
    <folder name="Loaders">
        <folder name="text">
            <folder name="brain+xml">
                <folder name="Factories">
                    <file name="foo-bar-brain-BrainDataLoader.instance">
                    </file>
                </folder>
            </folder>
        </folder>
    </folder>        
</filesystem>
```

Comment: Do you know what different attributes that can be used are?